# How do I delete a bad commit, while keeping later commits?

Tags: git

Let's say I have these commits in chronological order:

1. a
2. b
3. c

Now, I want to get rid of `b` but keep c, so that I have:

1. a
2. c

How do I do this?

*(there are no conflicts between `b` and `c`)*

Comment: Have you pushed any of these to a remote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you already pushed the changes to a remote, you could use:

```
$ git revert <hash of commit b>
```

that creates a new commit `d` that removes the changes of commit `b`

Comment: Cool!  And does it preserve commit `c`?

Comment: Literally what it's doing is creating a new commit that's the *inverse* of b, and committing it on top of c. It should roll out anything that came in on commit b, and leave a trail of the mistake and cleanup in history, which some people don't like, but I really do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you haven't already pushed to a remote repository, you can do an interactive rebase. See here:

http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the one commit from the HEAD, you can use cherry-pick on a different branch to bring just that commit over:

```
$ git checkout -b working
$ git reset --hard <hash of the commit `a`>
$ git cherry-pick <hash of the commit `c`>
```

The hard reset changes the working copy back to the state as of that commit, and then the cherry-pick applies the changes introduced in commit `c` directly on top of your working copy.

Answer (score 0):

The help for git rebase talks about this exact case!  Check it out:

```
A range of commits could also be removed with rebase. If we have the
   following situation:

           E---F---G---H---I---J  topicA

   then the command

       git rebase --onto topicA~5 topicA~3 topicA

   would result in the removal of commits F and G:

           E---H'---I'---J'  topicA

   This is useful if F and G were flawed in some way, or should not be
   part of topicA. Note that the argument to --onto and the <upstream>
   parameter can be any valid commit-ish.
```

Comment: Yes.  In the example, topicA~5 could be any commit; it would be 'c' in your question. topicA~3 would be 'a'